# Persistent `toSqlKey` for custom primary key

Tags: yesod, persistent

I am defining the following models, where `Category` has a non-integer primary key `code` of type `Text`.

```
Category
    code Text
    Primary code
    deriving Show Typeable

CategoryTreeNode
    name Text
    code CategoryId Maybe
    lft Int MigrationOnly default=0
    rgt Int MigrationOnly default=0
    deriving Show Typeable
```

For models defined without `Primary`, I could use `toSqlKey` to convert arbitrary `Int64`s into `Key Category`. Is there an equivalent function for models with custom primary keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer by looking through persistent's TH module:

https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/9396c278fc181fdac4a97c53637700417f41a478/persistent-template/Database/Persist/TH.hs#L857-L858

This line suggest that a `CategoryKey` is generated via TH and that is indeed the case:

```
let x :: Key Category
    x = CategoryKey "foobar"
```